# Best way to differentiate between possibilities of a generic type at runtime?

Tags: typescript

I have a generic type that can be one of 6 possibilities:

```
type Attribute<T> = {
  name: string;
  value: T | null;
};

type StringAttribute = Attribute<string>;
type BoolAttribute = Attribute<boolean>;
type NumberAttribute = Attribute<number>;
type NumberArrayAttribute = Attribute<number[]>;
type PointAttribute = Attribute<Point>;
type PointArrayAttribute = Attribute<Point[]>;
```

I want to differentiate between these at runtime. In pseudo-code:

```
[..attributes].forEach((attr) => setAttribute(attr, target))

function setAttribute(attr: Attribute<string | boolean | number | number[] | point | point[]>, target: ExtendedElement) {
  ...
  if (isNumberArrayAttribute(attr)) {
   target.setNumberArrayAttribute(attr.name, attr.value)
  }
  ...
}
```

Since the TypeScript types can't be inspected at rum-time I need to write some JavaScript code to mimic the TypeScript types. I see two alternative solutions

User defined type guards:

```
function isNumberArray(val: any): val is number[] {
  if (!val.isArray()) {
    return false;
  }
  return val.every((v) => typeof v === "number")
} 

function setAttribute(attr: Attribute<string | boolean | number | number[] | point | point[]>, target: ExtendedElement) {
  ...
  if (isNumberArray(attr.value)) {
    target.setAttr(attr.name, attr.value)
  }
  ...
}
```

Classes:

```
class NumberArrayAttribute extends Attribute {
  name: string
  value: number[]
  constructor(name: string, value: number[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value= value;
  }
}

function setAttribute(attr: Attribute<string | boolean | number | number[] | point | point[]>, target: ExtendedElement) {
  ...
  if (attr instanceof NumberArrayAttribute) {
    target.setNumberArrayAttribute(attr.name, attr.value)
  }
  ...
}
```

To my question:

- I can't choose between the user defined type guards approach and the class approach. What would you say are the advantages of each? Can one said to be better or more idiomatic than the other?
- Is something fishy about my example? Am I thinking about my problem the wrong way. Do you see some other approach I should be using?

Comment: The class approach doesn't validate the elements of the array.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: It doesn't at run-time, but it does at compile-time. With the class approach, the ts compiler validates that the value passed to the constructor is a number array.

Comment: So would an assignment like `const x: NumberArrayAttribute = {name: 'number array attr 1', value: ['hello']}`. You asked about runtime validation however, so it's a red herring

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to differentiate generic types in your function *setAttribute*?
If you do so, every time you add a new *Attribute* you also need to update your function *setAttribute*.

In my opinion, every attribute instance should know how to do their job of setting the "attribute".

Consider this interface:

```
interface Attribute<T> {
  name: string;
  value: T | null;
  guard(): boolean;
  setAttribute(target: ExtendedElement): void;
};
```

and this class:

```
class NumberArrayAttribute implements Attribute<number[]> {
  name: string;
  value: number[];

  constructor(name: string, value: number[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value= value;
  }

  public guard(): boolean {
    return this.value.isArray() && this.value.every((v) => typeof v === "number");
  }

  public setAttribute(target: ExtendedElement): void {
    target.setAttribute(this.name, this.value)
  }
}
```

The class knows how to perform both the *guard* and the *setAttribute*.
Now you can create as many Attribute<> classes as you want, without changing the function setAttribute:

```
function setAttribute(){
   [...attributes].forEach((attr: Attribute<any>) => {
       if (attr.guard()){
          attr.setAttribute(target)
       }
   })
}
```